# send data from raspberry to spring web application remotely

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, raspberry-pi

i
I want to have this architecture....
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHbPb.png

Can you help me? I can't understand How should I send data from respberry to web server.
I have a spring mvc webapplication...user should be able to measure something(for example temperature) and senf it through web application interface(jsp page). I can write a webservice to post data from form to webserver.
But How should I send data from raspberry to form?
or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between Pi and Spring App use **REST** (like POST, GET methods with JSON/XML as representation). You can either make Raspberry Pi just spam Spring application with data per X time or make Raspberry Pi a server so Spring will send requests to Raspberry Pi and Raspberry Pi will return data. The second way requires building RESTful API on Raspberry.

First way.

```
PI: here is your temperature (POST /temperature)
PI: here is your temperature (POST /temperature)
PI: here is your temperature (POST /temperature)
PI: here is your temperature (POST /temperature)
PI: here is your temperature (POST /temperature)
```

Second way.

```
SPRING: give me temperature (GET /temperature)
PI: here is your temperature (returns JSON)
SPRING retrives data from JSON and saves it into database.
```

You can learn how to build RESTful Web Service here: [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and how to consume RESTful Web Service: [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).

Remember that you can use Java on Raspberry Pi so you can write Spring application with Pi4J.

After you done buidling you will just get data from database and present it to user.

Note: if you want to transport a lot of data with small delay then you should consider using typical TCP/UDP connection.

Comment: Thank you so much...If i want to send data more than once per each request, what should I do?(solution except socket)

Comment: You can just make several requests, it is normal. You can also do like: `SPRING: give me 5 temperatures (GET /temperatures/5` and Raspberry will return `ok I will do it` and will send `here is your temperature (POST /temperature)` for 5 times per fe. 1 second.